# Moving text when hovering inside block

Tags: html, css, menu, padding

There is a simple horizontal menu. I want get an effect when you hover a button, the text on button must move to top a little. The problem is I am using "padding" to set a size of buttons. 
P.S. There is an effect when you hover a button: button must get bigger at the top part.

http://jsfiddle.net/e8d3aru1/3/

#### HTML

```
<div id="header-menu">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">First</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Second</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Third</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Fourth</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Fifth</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

#### CSS

```
#header-menu {
    margin-left: 31px;
    padding: 7px;   

}

#header-menu li {
    display: inline;
}

#header-menu a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    background-color: #ba202f;
    padding: 0.6em 0.6em 1em 0.6em;
    border-radius: 3px; 
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    transition: padding 0.2s ease;
}

#header-menu a:hover {
    color: #ba202f;
    background: #E8D17E;
    padding: 1em 0.6em 1em 0.6em;
    transition: padding 0.2s ease;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve something similar by setting your list styles as follows:

```
#header-menu li {
    display: inline;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 0;
    transition: bottom 0.2s ease;
}

#header-menu li:hover {
    bottom: .4em;
    transition: bottom 0.2s ease;
}
```

And change the padding in the `a:hover` style to:

```
padding: 0.6em 0.6em 1.4em 0.6em;
```

Working fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/wintvelt/364xub0y/1/).
And you do not need to change anything in your HTML (!)

Comment: Thanks for a great and simple implementation!

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/y6nc5p7z/1/)?

Wrap the text in the `<a></a>`a span like `<a><span>Text here</span></a>`

Give these `<span></span>` a `position:relative` in css and when hovered (`#header-menu a:hover span`) give it a negative top offset to move it up in the li

Hope this helps!

Comment: I suggest you to put the span in all tags , dont give an incomplete answer

Comment: @C0smo - I just did, I thought of that when I posted the answer, so I updated the fiddle